# How to create a rounded label/button with NOT interactive clipped area with Swift 3

Tags: swift, uibutton, rounded-corners

The dilemma: how to create a rounded button with NOT interactive clipped area.

Example:

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 50
myButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

Result:

[image]

Great! Though I don't want the grey areas to stay interactive. We absolutely can customize a button, draw a shape inside the view using **UIBezierPath** and check if every click's coordinates are within our custom path then react. Yet I want to believe there is a simpler way!

Would greatly appreciate any ideas! 
Thank you!

Comment: You can try to check the x/y of the touch point,against the rounded area aloud range of x/y point .. If inside do something else egnore it.

Comment: @Dasem Thank you very much for your suggestion. It's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that exists for me:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius).contains(point)
}
```